# Serve Video Files from gallery with http in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to play a local 360 video file with [flutter_video_360](https://github.com/kilroy80/flutter_video_360).
The package requires a URL.  I can play the file from the cloud, but as the file is large and varies between 4K to 8K resolution, I want to first download the file locally and then replay it from a local file.  Is there an existing package that can serve the files from the local gallery and provide a local http server to the flutter_video_360 player so that I can view the 360 videos files in a VR headset like Google Cardboard?

Answer (score 0):

Playing videos is a common task in app development, and Flutter apps are no exception. To play videos, the Flutter team provides the video_player plugin. You can use the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin to play videos stored on the file system, as an asset, or from the internet.

For details instruction check below link == https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/play-video

Comment: Thank you.  I can use video_player to play videos in equirectangular view.  I'd like the play the equirectangular videos with 360 navigation.  the flutter_video_360 package has 360 navigation (like viewable in a VR headset).  I'm like to use flutter_video_360 from a local file, not video_player.  Although video_player is good for standard non-360 videos, it does not have the 360 video navigation.